# Summary and Details section of a record in same report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have table like below

```
ParkingLot   Vehicle  City   Two/Four   Owner   Date        Fee
p1           v1       c1     Two        xxx     01-OCT-14   10
p1           v1       c1     Two        yyy     01-OCT-14   11
p1           v1       c1     Four       zzz     01-OCT-14   12
p1           v1       c2     Two        aaa     01-OCT-14   13
p1           v1       c2     Two        yyy     01-OCT-14   11
p1           v1       c2     Four       ddd     01-OCT-14   18
p1           v2       c1     Two        fff     01-OCT-14   20
p1           v2       c1     Two        yyy     01-OCT-14   10
p1           v2       c1     Four       hhh     01-OCT-14   10
p1           v2       c2     Two        xxx     01-OCT-14   54
p1           v2       c2     Two        iii     01-OCT-14   10
p1           v2       c2     Four       zzz     01-OCT-14   66
p1           v1       c1     Two        xxx     02-OCT-14   66
p1           v1       c1     Two        yyy     02-OCT-14   2
p1           v1       c1     Four       zzz     02-OCT-14   44
p1           v1       c2     Two        aaa     02-OCT-14   11
p1           v1       c2     Two        yyy     02-OCT-14   11
p1           v1       c2     Four       ddd     02-OCT-14   18
p1           v2       c1     Two        fff     02-OCT-14   44
p1           v2       c1     Two        yyy     02-OCT-14   10
p1           v2       c1     Four       hhh     02-OCT-14   88
p1           v2       c2     Two        xxx     02-OCT-14   54
p1           v2       c2     Two        iii     02-OCT-14   10
p1           v2       c2     Four       zzz     02-OCT-14   33
..........
```

This data i need in Crystal reports in below format

```
SUMMARY
P1

v1
ParkingLot   Vehicle  City   01-OCT-14    02-OCT-14
p1           v1       c1     33           112
p1           v1       c2     42           40
p1           v1    Total     66           152

v2
ParkingLot   Vehicle  City   01-OCT-14    02-OCT-14
p1           v2       c1     40           142
p1           v2       c2     130          97
p1           v2    Total     170          239

DETAILS
v1
ParkingLot   Vehicle  City   Two/Four   Owner   01-OCT-14   02-OCT-14
p1           v1       c1     Two        xxx     10          66
p1           v1       c1     Two        yyy     11          2
p1           v1       c1     Two        Total   21          68
p1           v1       c1     Four       zzz     12          44
p1           v1       c1     Four       Total   12          44
p1           v1       c1     ALL        Total   33          112

p1           v1       c2     Two        aaa     13          11
p1           v1       c2     Two        yyy     11          11
p1           v1       c2     Two        Total   24          22
p1           v1       c2     Four       ddd     18          18
p1           v1       c2     Four       Total   18          18
p1           v1       c1     ALL        Total   42          40

p1           v1       ALL    ALL        Total   66          152


v2
ParkingLot   Vehicle  City   Two/Four   Owner   01-OCT-14   02-OCT-14
p1           v2       c1     Two        fff     20          44
p1           v2       c1     Two        yyy     10          10
p1           v2       c1     Two        Total   30          54
p1           v2       c1     Four       hhh     10          88
p1           v2       c1     Four       Total   10          88
p1           v2       c1     ALL        Total   40          142

p1           v2       c2     Two        xxx     54          54
p1           v2       c2     Two        iii     10          10
p1           v2       c2     Two        Total   64          64
p1           v2       c2     Four       zzz     66          33
p1           v2       c2     Four       Total   66          33
p1           v2       c2     ALL        Total   130         97

p1           v2       ALL    ALL        Total   170         239
```

At first i tried with by making subreport for details section and main report for summary.
i successfully got desired result without cross tabs...

but as so many p1, p2, p3..... are there it will call subport for each and every detail scetion of P 
it will give performance impact...

please let me know how to do this in single report, with out cross tabs

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understood why `subreport` will be call so many times?

Comment: because i do have record like above not only for P1 for p2,p3, p4........ till p1000. i kept subreport in p1 group footer.. because for every parking slot i need summary and details section..

Answer (score 0):

use the same idea of making a subreport for details section and main report for summary, but on your subreport create a `Vehicle` and you will get the desire result even though you have hundred of different Vehicles. That subreport will be placed on your `report footer`, so it will show up after your `summary`